# How to add custom button in Hologram Play mode in 8th Wall

Tags: 8thwall-xr, 8thwall-web

I am developing 8th wall Hologram project. I want to add my custom button while hologram video is getting played. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a button using html/css like you would normally.

Here is an example with a 2D button over the WebAR experience:

https://www.8thwall.com/8thwall/animation-mixer-aframe